# How do I install 7zip in windows server CLI?

Tags: command-line

I am currently using windows server 2019 CLI running on virtualbox.
I need to Zip a folder and set a password, but obviously windows does not support this which means I need to download a third party software like 7ZIP in order to do so.

But the problem is I have no idea how im supposed to install 7zip using command line without access to a user interface. Any advice on how i could install 7zip through cmd? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may install 7Zip without the GUI by using the "silent" option when installing.
This will use the default installation values.

Silent install is done in a Command Prompt (cmd) that is run as Admin.
Use the following example command:

```
7z1900-x64.exe /S
```

The `/S` parameter stands for Silent installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with powershell using the following:

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("http://www.linktourl.net/7zip.exe","C:\tmp\7zip.exe")
```

Replace the url with the link to 7zip and file path to where you want it downloaded.